# Why does R give different value for one-sample K-S test?

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I want to do K-S test in R. In this case, I use `AdequacyModel` and `ks.test` in R.

My data:

```
data1 <- c(12.20,23.56,23.74,25.87,31.98,37,41.35,47.38,55.46,
           58.36,63.47,68.46,78.26,74.47,81.43,84,92,94,
           110,112,119,127,130,133,140,146,155,
           159,173,179,194,195,209,249,281,319,
           339,432,469,519,633,725,817,1776)
```

pdf of the distribution:

```
pdf_apiw <- function(par,x){
  a <- par[1]
  l <- par[2]
  b <- par[3]
  ((log(a))/(a-1))*l*b*x^(-(b+1))*exp(-l*x^(-b))*a^(exp(-l*x^(-b)))
}
```

cdf of the distribution:

```
cdf_apiw <- function(par,x){
  a <- par[1]
  l <- par[2]
  b <- par[3]
  (a^(exp(-l*x^(-b))) -1)/(a-1)
}
```

Parameters estimation:

```
set.seed(0)
model_apiw = goodness.fit(pdf = pdf_apiw, cdf = cdf_apiw, 
                          starts = c(50,1,1), data = data1, method = "PSO",
                          domain = c(0,Inf), mle = NULL, lim_inf = c(0,0,0),
                          lim_sup = c(300,20,2),
                          N = 50, S = 250, prop = 0.1)
model_apiw
```

And the K-S result of this code is

```
$KS

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  data
D = 0.076581, p-value = 0.9411
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

After that, I check by using `ks.test` and get different value of $D$ and $p$-value.

```
cdf_apiw1 <- function(a,l,b,x){
  a <- model_apiw$mle[1]
  l <- model_apiw$mle[2]
  b <- model_apiw$mle[3]
  x <- data1
  (a^(exp(-l*x^(-b))) -1)/(a-1)
}

ks.test(data1, cdf_apiw1)
```

Result:

```
One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  data1
D = 0.09354, p-value = 0.802
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

How can this happen? Can anyone explain to me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are passing different reference distributions in your two calls to `ks.test`.  Please explain, then, why you expect the outputs to be the same.

Comment: Why different distributions? The second one with ```ks.test``` is the same cdf as before, but with the estimated parameters. Since it is the same K-S test, I think the outputs should be the same.

Comment: If I understand your code and the documentation of the functions correctly, ```goodness.fit``` estimates the parameters of ```cdf.apiw``` and computes the KS-test taking into account the uncertainty of the parameter estimates, whereas ```ks.test``` assumes that the parameter values as estimated by ```goodness.fit``` are fixed and known.  This explains different p-values (the distribution of the test statistic changes if parameters can vary as well), but I'd still think that the statistic value ```D``` should be the same if ```cdf_apiw1``` is implemented correctly (about which I'm not sure).